# Passing typedef structure as call by reference in C

Tags: c, pass-by-reference, singly-linked-list

I am trying to create a linked list in C and my code is as below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}node_t;


void insert_into_list(node_t *,int);
void print_list(node_t *);
node_t *create_node(int );



void insert_into_list(node_t *head, int value){
    node_t *temp ;
    temp = create_node(value);
    if(head == NULL){
        printf("Inserting node for the first time\n");
        head = temp;
    }else {
        head->next = temp;
    }

}
void print_list(node_t *head){
    node_t *current = head;
    while(current!=NULL){
        printf("%d----->",current->data);
        current = current->next;
    }
    printf("NULL");
}
node_t *create_node(int value){
    node_t *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    if(new_node==NULL){
        printf("Memory allocation failed for the list creation. :(");
        return NULL;
    }
    new_node->data = value;
    new_node->next = NULL;
    return new_node;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    node_t *head = NULL;
    insert_into_list(head,10);
    if(head==NULL){
        printf("Still head is NULL :(");
    }else{
        printf("Head is not NULL:)");
    }
    print_list(head);
    return 0;
}
```

In `main`, I am calling insert_into_list and even after successful memory allocation, i am not able to get the head value with the newly created node. Still showing the value as NULL.

I have debugged with gdb and found that upto below code, head is not NULL

```
printf("Inserting node for the first time\n");
head = temp;
```

I thought I am passing by reference and expected the value to get reflected in the caller function.

Please correct me.

Comment: Technically, you are passing a pointer. Although 'by reference' could be applied to this, it generally isn't to avoid confusion with passing by reference in c++ (which is different).

Comment: There is no "pass by reference" in C. I f you want initialise the pointer value itself you need to pass the address of the pointer down to the function.

Comment: You are passing the actual node structure that head points to "by reference" - you are not passing the head pointer "by reference".  Change the function to `void insert_into_list(node_t **,int);` and call it with `insert_into_list(&head,10);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to pass by reference (or rather, the equivalent) in C you must pass a pointer. To pass a pointer by reference you have to pass a pointer to the pointer.

So in e.g. `insert_into_list` you must declare `head` as a pointer to a pointer:

```
void insert_into_list(node_t **head, int value)
```

And use the dereference operator when accessing the `head` variable.

You call it using the address-of operator `&`:

```
node_t *head = NULL;
insert_into_list(&head,10);
```

Comment: For completeness: If doing a proposed by this answer then inside `insert_into_list()` replace `head` with `(*head)`.

Comment: Thanks Joachim and alk :)